# Before-skip alignment problems with Tasks package; particularly when nested within an enumerate list

Tags: spacing, enumerate, tasks

When a `tasks` environment is positioned within an enumerate list, there is a misalignment; tasks will sit below the enumeration item:

[image]

Please see below for MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  \begin{tasks}[before-skip=-1cm](3)
    \task a
    \task b
    \task c
  \end{tasks}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Even if you provide a `before-skip`, I have offered a ridiculous one for example, this cannot be adjusted; the `before-skip` seems to provide no effect.

Desired outcome is for the tasks list (a, b, c) to sit vertically flush with the enumerate (1., 2., 3.).

Just FYI: I cannot define 1., 2. and 3. with tasks; I need to use the enumerate list for the highest level of items for other reasons external to this. I am currently doing this very inefficiently with `\vspace{}` before the tasks which is what I wish to eliminate if possible.